# How does this Java sorting work?

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

The following code is working fine. But I can't understand how it works? Could you please explain? Especially the method signature of `sortEmployeeByCriteria` (see below).

I understood it returns `List<T>` but what is `<T, U extends Comparable<? super U>>`?

```
public static void sortIt() {
    Employee[] employees = new Employee[] {
        new Employee("John", 25, 3000.0, 9922001),
        new Employee("Ace", 22, 20000.0, 5924001),
        new Employee("Keith", 35, 4000.0, 3924401)
    };

    List<Employee> employeeList  = Arrays.asList(employees);
    List<Employee> list = sortEmployeeByCriteria(employeeList, Employee::getName);
    list.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}

// But could you please explain the method signature how is it working
public static <T, U extends Comparable<? super U>> List<T> sortEmployeeByCriteria( List<T> list, Function<? super T, ? extends U> byCriteria) {
    Comparator<? super T> comparator = Comparator.comparing(byCriteria);
    list.sort(comparator);
    return list;
}
```

Comment: sortEmployeeByCriteria takes as parameters a List of T and a function doing T -> U. This function is used in Comparator#comparing so we need some bounds on U. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-

Comment: Note that this example does not use a lambda function anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer lies in the first line of the `sortEmployeeByCriteria()`:

```
Comparator<? super T> comparator = Comparator.comparing(byCriteria);
```

Looking at the [documentation of `Comparator.comparing()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) (a static method, same as `sortEmployeeByCriteria()`):

> `static <T,U extends Comparable<? super U>> Comparator<T>`
>   `comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor)`
>
> Accepts a
>   function that extracts a Comparable sort key from a type T, and
>   returns a Comparator that compares by that sort key.

So the `<T, U extends Comparable<? super U>>` is a type parameter in a `static` method (`static <T> void someMethod(U objectOfTypeU)`), which has some bounds required by the `Comparator.comparing()` method. It also allows you to use (generic) type `T` as a return value (i.e. `List<T>`).

Answer (score 1):

It's not a lambda - it's a method reference (the `Employee::getName` part). `sortEmployeeByCriteria` is just an ordinary generic static method, taking a List of type T, and a [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) which takes a T (or subclass) and produces something of type U (or subclass) and returns a (sorted) List of type T.

The unusual part is probably [Comparator#comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-), which creates a Comparator which will compare `T`s by the given mapping, i.e. it transforms `T`, in your case an `Employee`, to `U`, in your case a `String` (result of `getName`), which it knows how to compare because String implements Comparable. It then proceeds to actually sort them using `List#sort(Comparator)`.

`Employee::getName` is basically a shorthand, a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) you can pass instead of creating your own `Function` instance.